# ITMS-90846: Invalid bundle identifier when uploading App Clip

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store, apple-appclips

We have built our App Clip as part of our main App. However when we submit our app into test flight, we are getting an error about invalid bundle identifier. Any advice or tips on fixing this problem:

```
ITMS-90846: Invalid bundle identifier - The bundle identifier 'companyName.appName.Clip' of the app clip 'appName.app/AppClips/appName_appclip.app' conflicts with the bundle identifier of an existing app that you have submitted. Create a unique bundle identifier for your app clip.
```

It is possibly that we may have submitted a test version to test flight (but not to App Store) when App Clip originally came out few months ago just to understand its potential and that original App Clip was deleted from our development environment to build the new App Clip. After searching on stackoverflow and the internet, I have not seen a good answer on how to solve this problem so looking for help from the group.

Comment: did you ever resolve this? I am having the same issue.